# using "new" and "delete" inside class function

Tags: c++, heap-memory, arduino-c++

I want to be sure that using `new` and `delete` to free heap memory is done as needed.

Following function returns a `char *`. Inside each function I use `new` for the returned value, and I `delete` afterwards.

Is it the right way to free heap memory for function return?

```
const char *myIOT2::_devName()
{
    char *ret = new char[MaxTopicLength2];
    if (strcmp(addGroupTopic, "") != 0)
    {
        snprintf(ret, MaxTopicLength2, "%s/%s/%s", prefixTopic, addGroupTopic, deviceTopic);
    }
    else
    {
        snprintf(ret, MaxTopicLength2, "%s/%s", prefixTopic, deviceTopic);
    }
    return ret;
}
const char *myIOT2::_availName()
{
    char *ret = new char[MaxTopicLength2];
    const char *DEV = _devName();
    snprintf(ret, MaxTopicLength2, "%s/Avail", DEV);
    delete DEV;
    return ret;
}
```

To point out: the fact the I `DEV`: `const char *DEV = _devName();` in order to use it as a parameter in `snprintf(ret, MaxTopicLength2, "%s/Avail", DEV);` just to be able to `delete` it later as `delete DEV;` - is this correct?

Comment: And what is your question? You didn't ask one

Comment: @chrisl - you right. I'll add it. Is the way I did it is the correct way?

Comment: Seems legit at first glance. Does it work correctly? Though this is more of a C++ question. And be aware, that using dynamic memory allocation on microcontrollers can lead to heap fragmentation, so that you may run out of memory very fast. This is the case for all microcontrollers but is worse on those with low memory (like with the Arduino Uno).

Comment: Looks fine to me, though for this I prefer to use malloc() / free() since I'm trained in C more than C++ and I see new/delete as more for objects.

Comment: please see added explanation update

Comment: You should `delete[]`, rather than `delete`, the `DEV` pointer.

Comment: @EdgarBonet although it is a pointer?

Comment: When `new` went with `[]`, then also the corresponding `delete`  needs them.

Comment: Why not just use `String`?

Comment: Warning: frequent allocation and release of arbitrary lengths of dynamic storage can fragment memory, leading to the inability to allocate storage even though there is still plenty of memory left. Its just all in scattered and unusably small amounts. On a lightweight system like Arduino  this can lead to much weeping and gnashing of teeth.

Comment: @user4581301 since I don't want to keep char arrays when not needed (esp when dealing with MCU's) since stability issues are on stake here- what would you do differently ?

Comment: If it all comes and goes quickly (it sure looks like it for `DEV`) and if you have only one thread, you'll probably be safe. If `DEV`'s maximum length is known at compile time (`MaxTopicLength2` suggests it might be) and short (so we won't overflow the stack), I'd automatically allocate it in `_availName`, pass it into `_devName` and let scope handle it. Gets rid of one of the allocations. If you can do the same with whatever calls `_availName`, there is no possibility of fragmentations (and probably be a bit faster, too).

Comment: @EdgarBonet the word is 'must' not 'should' for delete[]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At least as I see things, you really only have two sane choices here. One is for the caller to handle all the memory management. The other is for the callee to handle all the memory management.

But what you're doing right now (callee handles allocation, caller handles de-allocation) is a path to madness and memory leaks.

If the caller is going to manage the memory, this all becomes fairly simple:

```cpp
const char *myIOT2::_devName(char *ret, size_t maxlen)
{
    if (strcmp(addGroupTopic, "") != 0)
    {
        snprintf(ret, maxlen, "%s/%s/%s", prefixTopic, addGroupTopic, deviceTopic);
    }
    else
    {
        snprintf(ret, maxlen, "%s/%s", prefixTopic, deviceTopic);
    }
    return ret;
}
```

If the callee is going to handle all the memory management, you'd normally use `std::string`. Since you're on an Arduino, however, `std::string` isn't available, and you need to use their own `String` class instead. Either way, you simply allocate a `String` object and put your contents into it. It takes care of the actual memory allocation to hold the contents, and will free its contents when the `String` object is destroyed.

Given the small amount of memory normally available on an Arduino, having the caller allocate the memory is *usually* going to work out better. But (especially if this is something that doesn't happen very often, so you won't run into heap fragmentation problems) allocating space on the heap can work reasonably well also.

But I'll repeat: trying to mix memory management so the callee allocates and the caller deletes...is the stuff of nightmares. When you read about C++ circa 1993, and hear about lots of problems with memory leaks...this is exactly the sort of thing that led to them.

Comment: Also consider having your function return the length needed (the return value from snprintf) rather than a copy of the argument.  That way you can detect when the buffer is too small and do something about it.

Comment: Thank your answer. 2 things I'm not fully sure I understand 1) function returns 'ret' and also has it as an argument. why is that ? does `char *ret` is an array I pass as a argument? 2) you suggestion to use as a `String` meaning that function will be defined as `String myIOT2::_devName()` while it returns a `String` ?

Comment: There's no particular need for it to return the argument, since it's just returning the same thing that was passed in. And yes, that's how a version using `String` would be defined.

Answer (score 2):

`ret` allocated memory:

```
const char *myIOT2::_devName()
{
    char *ret = new char[MaxTopicLength2];
    return ret;
}
```

And below, you'll see that by deleting DEV, you will free the memory, because it's actually `ret`. But this time, you should remove `ret2` somewhere else since it's the return value and there's no way to delete it inside that scope:

```
const char *myIOT2::_availName()
{
    char *ret2 = new char[MaxTopicLength2];
    const char *DEV = _devName();
    delete[] DEV;
    return ret2;
}
```

Also, note the following:

```
char* str = new char [30]; // Give str a memory address.

// delete [] str; // Remove the first comment marking in this line to correct.

str = new char [60]; /* Give str another memory address with
                                                    the first one gone forever.*/

delete [] str; // This deletes the 60 bytes, not just the first 30.
```